# FatalThrowableError bootstrap/cache/services.php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Sometimes I am getting Errors from bootstrap/cache/services.php Laravel 5.6
And I don't understand why I am getting them and how to fix.

```
{"message":"syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ')'","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError","code":0,"file":"\/app\/bootstrap\/cache\/services.php:130","line":0,"trace":"\/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/ProviderRepository.php:92; \/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/ProviderRepository.php:55; \/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Application.php:548; \/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Bootstrap\/RegisterProviders.php:17; \/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Application.php:206; \/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Console\/Kernel.php:297; \/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Console\/Kernel.php:120; \/app\/artisan:35"}
```

or

```
     {"message":"syntax error, unexpected ''command.queue.resta' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ')'","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError","code":0,"file":"\/app\/bootstrap\/cache\/services.php:127","line":0,"trace":"\/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/ProviderRepository.php:92; \/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/ProviderRepository.php:55; \/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Application.php:548; \/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Bootstrap\/RegisterProviders.php:17; \/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Application.php:206; \/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Console\/Kernel.php:297; \/app\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Console\/Kernel.php:120; \/app\/artisan:35"}
```

Comment: you are missing ')' in one of you files

Comment: you should not edit `/app/bootstrap/cache/services.php` manually. Delete it and things should start working.

Comment: @SviesusAlus I tried to delete this file and laravel generated it again, but this errors shows again